# What is go template variable for .md file?

Tags: hugo

I am creating a tutorial blog. it needs to be collaborative so I need to provide the link for the corresponding file in GitHub (only content folder)

so what is golang template variable to get the file name

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did mine:

```
<p class="post-path">content\{{ .File.Path }}</p>
```

Then it appears in the page as:

```
content\posts\2019-my-post.md
```

If you want just the filename part:

```
{{ .File.LogicalName }}
```

See [this](https://gohugo.io/variables/files/) for more options.